# Unable to display asp panel using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have a asp panel as below.

```
 <asp:Panel ID="panele" runat="server">

 <tr><td><fieldset ID="fsFieldset" class="crossbrowserfieldselect"> 
 <legend align="left">Show the current values</legend>
 </td>
 <tr> <td><asp:Textbox id ="txtstudent" runat"server"></td>

 <asp:panel>
```

There are many more text boxes and dropdownlists inside the fieldset and to reduce the complexity I did not put the entire code. I have this aspx page and it has 3 modes(select, update,insert). In select mode, aspx page should not display panel. By default the asp panel is visible. I am making it invisible in one of the functions in code behind that drives select mode as shown below. All the controls are readonly in this mode.

```
enter code here

function selectvalues ()
{
panele.Visible=False; /*code behind */
}
```

In insert mode, panel should be displayed and working as expected. In update mode, when user tries to edit date of birth value (it is date picker control), the panel should be displayed.Update mode also uses the above function and only when date of birth value is selected the panel should be displayed. Hence I wrote a javascript code to display panel as below.

```
 <Datechooser Width="100px" runat="server" ID="BirthDate" 
  onselect="return setpanelcontrols();"                              
 </Datechooser>


enter code here

function setpanelcontrols() 
{
var objpanele=document.getElementById("<%=panele.ClientID%>");
objpanele.style.display="block";
return true;
}
```

When I select date of birth, the panel is not displayed. I dont know whats wrong. I really appreciate any help on this.

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls with `Visible=False` are not rendered as part of the HTML. Try hiding and showing trough CSS like this in your code behind:

```
 panele.CssClass= "myHidePnlclass";
```

or what I think will fit your current code:

```
panele.Style["display"] = "none";
```

Comment: But it is not working. I tried the below methods as you suggested, but for reason am unable to hide it.

Comment: I tested this on my local and it worked fine. Are you there is no other code interfering?

Comment: panele.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none") ; panele.Style.Add("display","none");  Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
             'sb.Append(Chr(13) & "<script language=javascript>" & Chr(13))
             '   Me.panele.Style("display")="hidden"
             '    sb.Append("</script>" & Chr(13))   (my code is in vb)

Comment: Ya..i did the same and html displays all the controls inside panel

Comment: My mistake it was display none instead of hidden panele.Style("display") = "none";

Comment: Thank you for the help and this solved my issue. I was not properly closing tags which lead to improper HTML rendering.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the asp:Control Visible Property to false from code behind. The browser doesn't render that element and you can't make it visible from client side (jquery, javascript) then.

To hide it from code behind Replace:

```
panele.Visible=False;
```

With

```
panele.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is problem with tags. Panel is rendered as div and i have applied the css style with visibily hidden. Finally when i tried to inspect element, i found an interesting thing. Below is the asp code as I posted before. However I added a div to see whats happening.

```
 <tr><td><fieldset ID="fsFieldset" class="crossbrowserfieldselect"> 
 <legend align="left">Show the current values</legend>
 </td>
 <tr> <td><asp:Textbox id ="txtstudent" runat"server"></td>

  <asp:panel>
  </div>
```

Below is the css via inspect element

```
   <div id="BasicInfo_pane" style="visibility:hidden;">
                 <div id="BasicInfo_panele" class="styleset1" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;">
 </div></div>

    <table> 
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td> fieldset="fsFieldset"........ </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

Clearly for some reason the panel has ended before fieldset as div's ended before fieldset (i think start and end tags are not properly organized, dont know why). And I think this is the reason the fieldset inside panel is not hidden. Panel is hidden and as fieldset is not hidden the output is displayed in browser and I misunderstood that panel is not hidden.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
 ClientIDMode="Static"
```

on the asp panel and then in JavaScript:

```
 function selectvalues ()
 {
     if(YOUR CONDITION){
         $('#panele').hide();
     }
 }
```

Comment: You are using JQUERY without giving any context. The question does not mention the use of it